# How can I inject unique identifiers to query result?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I'm making a query with Apollo client.
The response contains car property which is an array.
Inside car items there is no unique identifiers. Therefore Apollo client is not caching them properly.

Here is my query:

```
query GetCars {
  cars: car_view {
     brand,
     year
  }
}
```

In my case Id doesn't exist as property in database.
How can I inject `id` to this query from `@apollo/client`

Answer (score 0):

Create a resolver for the `id`:

```
car: {
  id: ({ brand, year }) => `${brand}-${year}`
}
```

This is a synthetic id made up of brand and year. Assuming that combination is unique then this should be sufficient. If not you may have to include the model of the car.